# django error in url generated by form, url is not matching. getting unwanted comma between my query search

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to submit a form and after that i want to call a specific view but my url is not matching "," is coming in between.

My form:

```
<form action={% url "blog:post_search" %}, method="get">
<input type="text" name="query">
<input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

My view:

```
def post_search(request):
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        search_query = SearchQuery(request.GET['query'])
        search_vector = SearchVector('title', 'body')
        result = Post.objects.annotate(search=search_vector,
                    rank=SearchRank(search_vector,search_query)
                    ).filter(search=search_query).order_by('-rank')
        return render(request,'blog/post/search.html',{'query':search_query,
                                                   'result':result})
```

My urls:

```
path('search/', views.post_search, name='post_search')
```

Raised error:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/search/,?query=confused Using the
>   URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL  patterns,
>   in this order: admin/ blog/ [name='post_list'] blog/
>   tag// [name='post_list_by_tag'] blog/
>   //// [name='post_details']
>   blog/ /share/ [name='post_share'] blog/ search/
>   [name='post_search'] sitemap.xml
>   [name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'] The current path,
>   blog/search/,, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you put a comma in your form tag. HTML attributes should be quoted and not separated by commas.

```
<form action="{% url "blog:post_search" %}" method="get">
```